# Keras Dense models with shared weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, tf.keras

I would like to create a Dense model in keras with shared weights. My approach is described below. I have one Dense network called `dense`. `dense_x`, `dense_y` and `dense_z` should share weights (i.e. use `dense`). The output of these three networks is then concatenated and feed in another dense network.

However, somehow this approach does not work. How can I use shared weights in the correct way?

```
num_nodes = 310
input_tensor_x = Input(shape=(310,))
input_tensor_y = Input(shape=(310,))
input_tensor_z = Input(shape=(310,))

dense = Dense(num_nodes)
dense = BatchNormalization()(dense)
dense = Activation('relu')(dense)
dense = Dropout(0.4)(dense)

dense = Dense(num_nodes // 2)
dense = BatchNormalization()(dense)
dense = Activation('relu')(dense)
dense = Dropout(0.4)(dense)

dense = Dense(num_nodes // 4)
dense = BatchNormalization()(dense)
dense = Activation('relu')(dense)
dense = Dropout(0.4)(dense)

dense_x = dense(input_tensor_x) #<=== shared above dense network
dense_y = dense(input_tensor_y) #<=== shared above dense network
dense_z = dense(input_tensor_z) #<=== shared above dense network
merge_layer = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([dense_x, dense_y, dense_z])

merged_nodes = 3*(num_nodes // 4) // 2
dense2 = Dense(merged_nodes)(merge_layer)
dense2 = BatchNormalization()(dense2)
dense2 = Activation('relu')(dense2)
dense2 = Dropout(0.4)(dense2)

dense2 = Dense(merged_nodes // 2)(dense2)
dense2 = BatchNormalization()(dense2)
dense2 = Activation('relu')(dense2)
dense2 = Dropout(0.4)(dense2)

output_tensor = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(dense2)

fcnn_model = Model(inputs=[input_tensor_x, input_tensor_y, input_tensor_z], outputs=output_tensor)
opt = Adam(lr=learning_rate)
fcnn_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.AUC()])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simplest way is to initialize the shared layers at the top and then pass the following layers into them. pay attention to not overwrite them.

I initialized a `Dense` layer and a `BatchNormalization` because they are the only layers with trainable weights

```
num_nodes = 310
input_tensor_x = Input(shape=(310,))
input_tensor_y = Input(shape=(310,))
input_tensor_z = Input(shape=(310,))

def shared_dense(inp):
    
    dense = Dense(num_nodes)(inp)
    dense = BatchNormalization()(dense)
    dense = Activation('relu')(dense)
    dense = Dropout(0.4)(dense)

    dense = Dense(num_nodes // 2)(dense)
    dense = BatchNormalization()(dense)
    dense = Activation('relu')(dense)
    dense = Dropout(0.4)(dense)

    dense = Dense(num_nodes // 4)(dense)
    dense = BatchNormalization()(dense)
    dense = Activation('relu')(dense)
    dense = Dropout(0.4)(dense)

    return Model(inp, dense, name='shared_dense')

shared_dense = shared_dense(Input(shape=(310,)))
dense_x = shared_dense(input_tensor_x) #<=== shared 
dense_y = shared_dense(input_tensor_y) #<=== shared 
dense_z = shared_dense(input_tensor_z) #<=== shared 

merge_layer = Concatenate()([dense_x, dense_y, dense_z])

merged_nodes = 3*(num_nodes // 4) // 2
dense2 = Dense(merged_nodes)(merge_layer)
dense2 = BatchNormalization()(dense2)
dense2 = Activation('relu')(dense2)
dense2 = Dropout(0.4)(dense2)

dense2 = Dense(merged_nodes // 2)(dense2)
dense2 = BatchNormalization()(dense2)
dense2 = Activation('relu')(dense2)
dense2 = Dropout(0.4)(dense2)

output_tensor = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(dense2)

fcnn_model = Model(inputs=[input_tensor_x, input_tensor_y, input_tensor_z], 
                   outputs=output_tensor)
fcnn_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-3), 
                   metrics=['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.AUC()])
```

Comment: Thanks for the edits. Yes that is exactly what I was looking for.